# Difference in a[:] and a in an expression

Tags: python, list, slice

I know the difference in `a[:]` and `a` in assignment to a variable and also the special case of slice assignment.

Suppose,

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

What is the difference between the following two statements?

```
b=a[:]+[6,7,8,9,10] #1   
b=a+[6,7,8,9,10] #2
```

In both cases, both `a` and `b` have the same values at the end.

I have referred the following links -

[When and why to use [:] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404340/when-and-why-to-use-in-python)

[Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

[Python why would you use [:] over =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433759/python-why-would-you-use-over)

They haven't mentioned their difference in an expression as such.

Comment: `[:]` select all the values of the list, it's a slicing character in python list, however, if there is a number after `:` it slice either from that index or to that index depending on the position before or after the `:`.

Comment: the first statement makes a (unnecessary) copy of `a` first. the second one does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a[:]` grabs a full slice of the list – in this context, it has no difference in effect since you're assigning to a new list (though it does copy the list, so it's slower at scale).

```py
# create the list.
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# see its address
>>> id(a)
4349194440
# see the (different) address of a copy
>>> id(a[:])
4350338120
# reassign the entire list using slice syntax
>>> a[:] = [5, 6, 7]
>>> a
[5, 6, 7]
# still the same first ID though
>>> id(a)
4349194440
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In python list slicing `a[:]` and `a` has only difference in their id's because `a[:]` is making an exact copy of `a` in another address location.

Also considering python immutable string  slicing `a[:]` and `a` have no difference.Both points to same address location.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5] 
b=a[:]+[6,7,8,9,10] #1  
b=a+[6,7,8,9,10] #2
```

**Case-1** `a[:]` , means you are slicing the sequence and a sequence can be anything like string, list etc. Basically this is read as `a[start:end:steps]`,where `start` `end` are our indexing values AND `steps` are number of jumps. If we do not provide any values then by default `start` = 0 AND `end` = last element of sequence AND `steps` = 1.  So in your case, you are simply taking the whole elements of list `a`.

**Case-2** `a` , It simply means the whole `a`

**Conclusion**:- With the help of `a[:]` you can get the desired elements.

**Examples**-->>

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[1:4]
>> [1,2,3]
a[::2]
>> [1,3]
```

I hope it may help you.